# Could not list the contents of because it is not a folder in Windows FTP server?

Tags: ftp, apache-commons-vfs

The root directory is: /ftp/kathir and the Change directory is : /ftp/kathir

This works pretty fine when the FTP server is linux. The same doesn't work on Windows.

I have configured Guilt FTP server to test the FTP operations locally and all permissions are given.

Could someone help me what might be the issue? Is the Issue with FTP server or FTP third party tool or any configuration is missing?

I am using Apache Commons VFS library to connect to the FTP server.

Thanks,
Kathir

Comment: Is the FTP active & passive port open? show us some codes.

Comment: It is in passive mode.FtpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setPassiveMode(opts, true);

Comment: The problem with the free Guilt FTP tool and later tried a couple of free FTP servers and found that War Daemon Manager worked fine. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the free Guilt FTP tool and later tried a couple of free FTP servers and found that War Daemon Manager worked fine. Thanks for the assistance.